# Can't use annotation inside method

Tags: java, eclipse, jersey

I am using jersey to implement REST api service in my product. To get the form parameter value I am trying to using @FormParam annotation inside my method. But in eclipse it throws error "The annotation @FormParam is disallowed for this location".

[image]

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Why would you need `@FormParam` if you are getting the parameter through `request.getParameter`? You should revisit your Jersey tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not put annotations inside methods. Annotations are usually placed before:

- Classes
- Methods and constructors
- Parameters of methods

[(however, more possibilities are available)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html)

In your case, [annotate a parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/FormParam.html):

```
public String addUser(@FormParam("emailid") String emailid, 
                      @FormParam("password") String password) {
   ...
}
```

that makes request.getParameter(...) unneeded.

[Check a full example.](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-formparam-example/)

Comment: The first line is just wrong. That specific annotation (`@FormParam`) is not allowed inside a method, other are (v.g. `@SuppressWarnings`)